# Delete some record and then rollback if condition fails in rails

Tags: mysql, transactions, ruby-on-rails-5.1

**Problem?**

I have a `Rails5` application. I have two models. `Team` and `Players`.
The association is  `has_many  & belongs_to` in between them.

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
end


class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Now, I want to perform `destroy` players before updating the `team` model. The condition is like below

```
def update
  @team.players.destroy_all if a
  ........
  if b
  .... some code.....
  elsif c
    @team.players.destroy_all
  end
  if @team.update_attributes(team_params)
    redirect_to teams_path
  else
  ... some code..
    render :edit
  end
end
```

**Note**

In `team_params`, I have `players_attributes`, so each time if a new entry is there I need to remove all old entries and then `@team.update_attributes` will insert the entries in `players`.

**Expectations**

If `@team.update_attributes(team_parmas)` fails, then `@team.players` should be **rolled back**.

**Things I tried**

I tried adding `Transactions` in the first line of `update` method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gem like paper trail to keep a history, but the nature of rails is to not be able to roll back transactions after committed. One way to mock this would be to keep the attributes in a transient collection of hashes and re-save them if you need the records once more. You could have logic like

```
team_players = @team.players.map(&:attributes)
```

Then if you need to 'roll back'

```
team_players.each do |team_player|
    TeamPlayer.create(team_player)
end
```

This will only work with basic attributes. If you have other model relations you will have to handle them with attributes also.